# execute() of Tasklet is never called

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a simple job which is tested in an integration test using JUnit. I define a tasklet in my job context and integrate it in a Spring Batch job bean. However, the execute() method of this tasklet is never called and I have no idea why. Do you have any idea why that is?

My job context:

```
<beans 
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:/launch-context-test.xml" />

<batch:job id="testJob">
    <batch:step id="testStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="myTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="myTasklet" class="de.something.MyTasklet" scope="step" />

<bean id="jobLauncherTestUtils" class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils" />
```

The tasklet is implemented like this:

```
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

public MyTasklet() {
    System.out.println("Tasklet initialized.");
}

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Execute Tasklet.");

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

And this my test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
    StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class, JobScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

@Resource
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherUtils;

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {

    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder(jobLauncherUtils.getUniqueJobParameters()).toJobParameters();
    jobLauncherUtils.launchJob(params);
}
```

When I execute my test1 using JUnit, it prints only "Tasklet initialized." to the console.

Answer (score 2):

The `JobLauncherTestUtils` needs to be told what job to run.  You need to inject the job into it in your configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="jobLauncherTestUtils" class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils">
    <property name="job" ref="testJob"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: The job itself runs without the job property. I tested the job with another step having reader, processor and writer without problems. It seems only this particular tasklet step is never executed, no matter if another step is executed before or if this tasklet step is the only step.